# Spatial locality in CUDA loops

Tags: c++, performance, cuda, unified-memory

I was reading the Even Easier Introduction to CUDA, and I was thinking about examples like this:

```
__global__
void add(int n, float *x, float *y)
{
  int index = threadIdx.x;
  int stride = blockDim.x;
  for (int i = index; i < n; i += stride)
      y[i] = x[i] + y[i];
}
```

In which each thread strides through the array. In normal CPU computing, one would rather split the array into contiguous sub-arrays that are splitted among the threads, so that they can each better exploit spatial locality.

Does this concept apply to CUDA's unified memory as well? I would like to understand what the most efficient approach would be in such a situation.

Comment: While NVIDIA calls them "threads", this is a misnomer. You should think of CUDA threads as of lanes of a SIMD vector processing unit. Then this pattern makes a lot more sense. That being said, this analogy doesn't hold on all levels and therefore they call it SIMT.

Comment: And CUDA supports SIMD types like float4 within each thread as smaller parallelization approach, too (which can reduce number of memory transactions for memory heavy kernels).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason a [grid-stride loop](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/) is beneficial for memory access is that it promotes ["coalesced" access to global memory](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/how-access-global-memory-efficiently-cuda-c-kernels/).  In a nutshell, coalesced access means that adjacent threads in the [warp](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#simt-architecture) are accessing adjacent locations in memory, on any given read or write cycle/operation, considered warp-wide.

The grid-stride loop arranges the indices across the warp to promote this pattern.

This is orthogonal to whether the memory was allocated with an "ordinary" device allocator (e.g. `cudaMalloc`) or a "unified" allocator (e.g. `cudaMallocManaged`).  In either case, the best way for device code to access such an allocation is using coalesced access.

You didn't ask about it, but [CUDA shared memory](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/using-shared-memory-cuda-cc/) also has one of its "optimal access patterns" consisting of adjacent threads in the warp accessing adjacent locations in (shared) memory.

Comment: A very important concept in this answer being the warp of 32 threads, which can be thought of as being executed together at the very same time.